# Selenium not firing Onchange in IE and not allowing page to Postback

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I have a web Application, where Once we select a drop down list the other one get loaded. Here with selenium once the drop down is selected, the page post back gets stopped and the second drop down does not get loaded. I have used the following codes. I even tried triggering the on `onchange` event.

```
WebElement selectElement = driver.findElement(By.name("ctrlFundTransfer$dropDownListWrittingCompany"));

String change=selectElement.getAttribute("onchange");

System.out.println("List Item " + change);

Select selectw = new Select(selectElement);

JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("alert(\"Executing\");"+change+";");
```

Kindly tell how to go about that page postback process for loading the second drop down as Selenium i preventing the page postback.

Comment: Could you post the url? Also, which browser are using for Selenium code to run?

Comment: Its a company website. I am using IE for testing now. Yes other browsers are working well.

Comment: pls post the html source

Comment: Html source i cant post...its just a <select id="name" onchange="javascript:"><option>1<option><option>2<option><option>3<option></select>....On selecting the dropdowns the onchange gets activated and populates another dropdown....Selenium is not allow it to post back to populate.

Comment: Have you tried including a wait before you try to select the second dropdown?

Comment: I have a implicit wait in place for about 60 seconds. It throws element is not Found message. But it takes only 188 ms. "Cannot locate option with index: 2"

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with GZIP compression. You may disable it and work.

http://forums.asp.net/t/1537438.aspx?Disable+GZip+compression+on+a+single+page

When in IE if I goto 'Tools', 'Internet Options', 'Advanced', then under 'HTTP 1.1 settings' uncheck both settings and run the page, it works.